# Display Current operation

Tags: powershell

I have around 14 GB of photos that need to be compressed. I use an application [`mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php).

Which so far I can do what I require that is compress the image by 50% using this one liner.

```
mogrify -quality 50% *.jpg
```

Now, that only works in the current folder, so I put together a very simple PS version:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\PHOTOGRAPHS -Include *.jpg -Recurse | foreach ($_) {
  mogrify -quality 50% $_.FullName
}
```

What I would like is the current filename to be displayed with path, but am struggling to be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply echo the full name of the file inside the `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\PHOTOGRAPHS -Include *.jpg -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $_.FullName
  mogrify -quality 50% $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always been a fan of `Write-Progress` myself...

```
Get-ChildItem E:\PHOTOGRAPHS -Include *.jpg -Recurse | foreach ($_) {
    Write-Progress $_.FullName
    mogrify -quality 50% $_.FullName
}
```

No screen scroll with that, and I guess it doesn't give you a list to track, but it seems clean to me.

Comment: Even thought the above post does what i wanted, i can also use this to.

Comment: Thanks again for this to.